# Loading texture(mtl) in java using vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin7

How to load mtl file in vaadin7 ? i am using ThreeJs addon for loading object but unable to load texture on it with mtl.

Comment: You need to post far more detail - for example your code and any errors you are getting.

Comment: I am able to load the file but  not able to read the values. i want to load the textures from mtl file on object in vaadin.i am using threejs addon for loading an object.

Comment: You need to post your code and the errors otherwise you'll never get an answer.

Comment: @PaulNUK i updated the code